# Desesctructurar Array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, dom, javascript-objeto

quisiera aplicar la desestructuración a un array que contiene objetos y con esas variables aplicarlas al DOM. Como lo veo tengo dos problemas. Necesito agrupar de alguna manera la propiedad "categoria" para que de se sumen las ocurrencias y por otro lado aplicar eso al DOM. Como puedo hacer esa desestructuración y agrupamiento??

```
// Funcion constructora objetos
function producto(id, nombre, precio, img, descripcion, categoria) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.img = img;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.categoria = categoria
}

const producto1 = new producto("001", "Living Carrara", 20000, "img/naomi-hebert-MP0bgaS_d1c-unsplash.jpg", "Living moderno de sofisticado estilo con marmol de Carrara", "Muebles Interior")
const producto2 = new producto("002", "Comedor Clásico", 190000, "img/home-2609600_1280.jpg", "Comedor Clásico estilo Renacentista", "Muebles Exterior" )
const producto3 = new producto("003", "Sofas Mágicos", 120000, "img/living-room-1835923_1280.jpg", "Sofas Indios traidos de India(?), especial para el dia del padre", "Muebles Interior")
const producto4 = new producto("004", "Espacios grandes para mentes amplias", 290000, "img/furniture-998265_1280.jpg", "No paga expensas", "Muebles Exterior")

// Spread de obejeto para crear uno nuevo

const producto5 = {
    ...producto4,
    id: "005",
    nombre: "Living Spread",
    descripcion: "Espaciomas spreader",
    }

// Array de objetos "producto"
const productos = [];
productos.push(producto1);
productos.push(producto2);
productos.push(producto3);
productos.push(producto4);
productos.push(producto5);

// Desestructuración de objetos
// Creacion de categorias con DOM

function desestructurar({categoria}){
    return(categoria)}

productos.forEach((producto) => {
    const categoria = desestructurar(producto)
    console.log(categoria)})
```

Comment: No está muy claro lo que quieres hacer, por ejemplo: ¿Para qué quieres desestructurar? ¿A qué te refieres con aplicar variables al DOM? Al menos proporciona el HTML actual y explica de qué forma se verá afectado con los productos. Recuerda que puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/551310/edit) tantas veces como sea necesario para que sea más clara.

Comment: Necesito desestructurar porque asi me lo pide un trabajo del curso que estoy haciendo. Y pensaba usar esas variables que surgen de la desestructuración para incluirlas en elementos del DOM

Comment: Solo se pueden desestrucutrar objetos iterables o usar el operador [spread (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) para clonar objetos con propiedades y valores, eso ya lo tienes al crear `producto5`. Y debo insistir en la necesidad de que agregues el HTML que quieres modificar y expliques de qué manera se van a usar los productos para eso.